# JavaScript widget code snippet on image onload

Tags: javascript, widget, wysiwyg

I'm working on a JavaScript widget (I actually have several I'd like to update) and hope to distill the embed code snippet down to just a single <img> tag with JavaScript in the onload attribute.  In the past I used a  along with an <img> tag.  Then I switched to just a <script> tag to make the widget non-blocking.  I'm working on the <img> only option for usability reasons.  It is easier to copy and paste to move the widget around if you don't have to switch into the source view of the WYSIWYG editor.  It is also really nice to have something you can visually see in a WYSIWYG editor.

Here's an example of the current draft of the snippet:

```
<img id='NotablePAD80' class='NotablePAD' src='//dev.notable.webapp.msu.edu/n.png' 
data-section='nathanlounds' onload="(function(d){ var i=d.getElementsByTagName('IMG')[0], 
u='https://dev.notable.webapp.msu.edu/n.js', 
j=i.previousSibling||i; if(j.src!==u) { var s=d.createElement('SCRIPT'); 
s.type='text/javascript'; s.src=u; i.parentNode.insertBefore(s,i);}})(document);" />
```

What is the best way to prevent the widget from executing pre-save in the WYSIWYG?  The loading of the widget can't change the DOM within the editor.

My ideas:

1. Look from the presence of the tinyMCE variable.  Don't process
   widget if it is defined.  TinyMCE is an editor I'd need to be
   compatible with.  But I'd likely need 'fixes' for other WYSIWYG too.
2. Examine the DOM and look for properties that are
   only present within a WYSIWYG, such as being inside an iframe.  But I need the widget to work within iframes.

There are problems with both of those options.    TinyMCE may not be defined yet when my widget executes.  The image load event gets triggered multiple times for some reason.  Ultimately I'd love a solution that would work universally.

Thoughts?  Brilliant solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Check if a parent of the image has contentEditable enabled, or if the body of the document is in designMode